# Existe una alternativa para virtualbox de las open-vm-tools?

Tags: virtualbox

Para VMware se puede utilizar herramientas como open-vm-tools, me gustaría saber si existe una alternativa similar para virtualBox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pues hasta donde sé, deberías instalar el paquete:

- virtualbox-guest-x11 (si tienes entorno gráfico)
- virtualbox-guest-utils (si no tienes entorno gráfico (headless)).

Espero sirva.
Saludos.

https://wiki.debian.org/VirtualBox#Installing_the_Guest_Additions_on_a_Debian_VM